# Is there a library with an alternative InsertAllOnSubmit implementation which uses SqlBulkCopy?

Tags: .net, sql-server, linq-to-sql

We know that Linq-To-Sql InsertAllOnSubmit sucks in terms of performance, but using SqlBulkCopy for mass insertions requires some coding. Have anyone found any code/library that uses SqlBulkCopy in a InsertAllOnSubmit alternative implementation as simple to use as the original?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this:
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/aviwortzel/archive/2008/05/06/implementing-sqlbulkcopy-in-linq-to-sql.aspx

Answer (score 2):

All I found that came close to produce such a library is this blog : [Batch Updates and Deletes with LINQ to SQL](http://www.aneyfamily.com/terryandann/post/2008/04/Batch-Updates-and-Deletes-with-LINQ-to-SQL.aspx)

It's a step in the right direction imo

**EDIT :**
In relation to that comment about the GetDeleteBatchCommand.  It's in the source code. Here's a the code :

```
private static DbCommand GetDeleteBatchCommand<TEntity>(this Table<TEntity> table, IQueryable<TEntity> entities) where TEntity : class
    {
        var deleteCommand = table.Context.GetCommand(entities);
        deleteCommand.CommandText = string.Format("DELETE {0}\r\n", table.GetDbName()) + GetBatchJoinQuery<TEntity>(table, entities);
        return deleteCommand;
    }
```

Comment: This post uses a non-existent method "GetDeleteBatchCommand" which is useless unless I find where it is implemented

Comment: It's an extension using Expression and Extensions.  I'm sure you could either contact the guy or build something around the UpdateBatch. It's well writen and there's even some comments! <gasp>